# C++ - MPIR: mpz_t to std::string?

Tags: c++, gmp

How do we convert mpz_t to std::string?

```
mpz_t Var;

// Var = 5000
mpz_init_set_ui( Var, 5000 );

std::string Str = "";
// Convert Var to std::string?

mpz_clear( Var );
```

Comment: Look at `mpz_class::get_str()`.

Comment: Take a look here http://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html

Comment: Build with `--enable-cxx` and `include "gmpxx.h"` to use the solution by @MarcGlisse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for [`mpz_get_str`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Converting-Integers.html):

```
char * tmp = mpz_get_str(NULL,10,Var);
std::string Str = tmp;

// In order to free the memory we need to get the right free function:
void (*freefunc)(void *, size_t);
mp_get_memory_functions (NULL, NULL, &freefunc);

// In order to use free one needs to give both the pointer and the block
// size. For tmp this is strlen(tmp) + 1, see [1].
freefunc(tmp, strlen(tmp) + 1);
```

However, you shouldn't use `mpz_t` in a C++ program. Use [`mpz_class`](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) instead, since it provides the `get_str()` method, which actually returns a `std::string` and not a pointer to some allocated memory.

Comment: You should not use free on the memory returned by mpz_get_str, you need to query the allocation functions with `mp_get_memory_functions`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I know, but I wanted to simplify that example. Also, if he didn't change the memory functions the default deallocater should be `free`. Other than that, he should simply use the C++ classes.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I'd love to see an example on how to use `mp_get_memory_functions` in order to destroy the `char *` returned by `mpz_get_str`. Could you please provide one?

Comment: There is one in `gmpxx.h`.

Comment: I should have added `mp_get_memory_functions` in the first place, that would have saved you both some time, sorry.

Comment: This is still invalid, at least sunCC would reject this (the typedef with extern "C" in gmpxx.h is important), although most other compilers would accept it. I agree that it is a pain.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Feel free to edit it. I wouldn't use this snippet ever, since mixing `mpz_get_str` with `std::string` simply feels wrong: *"Other than that, he should simply use the C++ classes."*